# Eventmachine calls callback twice

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I tried to launch [eventmachine httpserver](https://github.com/eventmachine/evma_httpserver) example, but I've added simple `puts` in the `process_http_request` method. To my surprise, when I access localhost:8080 from browser, I see `puts` output in terminal twice.

Why is it printed twice? Is it a bug? Maybe I misunderstand something in eventmachine.
You can see my example below.

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'evma_httpserver'

class MyHttpServer < EM::Connection
  include EM::HttpServer

  def post_init
    super
    no_environment_strings
  end

  def process_http_request
    response = EM::DelegatedHttpResponse.new(self)
    response.status = 200
    response.content_type 'text/html'
    response.content = '<center><h1>Hi there</h1></center>'
    puts 'my_test_string'
    response.send_response
  end
end

EM.run do
  EM.start_server '0.0.0.0', 8080, MyHttpServer
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a request for the favicon. The second one is a request for the page body. If you want to call it a bug, it is your bug, not the library's.

Comment: Oh, I should print out received data and then I would see "get /favicon.ico", but thank you a lot :)